# simple way to select all record that are between two date

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, sqlcommand

are there a simple way to select all record that are between two date. should i use `datetime` for filed type or i can use string type too. something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE datetime_update      is between date1 and date2
```

- i use string filed type for some reasons so that would be better.

i try this command in my c# project but it return noting. where am i miss understanding ?

```
SELECT        user_id, sharj_value, datetime_update
FROM            users
WHERE        (user_id = 0653193963) AND (datetime BETWEEN '1390/07/12%' AND '1390/07/14%')
```

and this is sample of data in table

```
filed names    user_id    sharj_value      datetime_update

             0653193963      60000       1390/7/12 08:00:15  
             0653193963      40000       1390/7/13 08:18:44 
             0653193963      40000       1390/7/13 08:20:35
```

it suppose to return two last row i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT user_id, sharj_value, datetime
  FROM users
 WHERE user_id = 0653193963 AND datetime BETWEEN '1390/07/12 00:00:00' AND '1390/07/14 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Okie..that should be help you!

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, this T-SQL syntax should work:

```
SELECT user_id, sharj_value, [datetime]
FROM users
WHERE user_id = 06531939630 AND [datetime] BETWEEN '1390-07-12' AND '1390-07-14'
```

Note, too, that some locales have year-month-day (like America), and others use year-day-month.

You might also want to look at SQL-Server's "[set dateformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)"

Comment: that wouldn't help,i change filed name too but noting return again. and its a string filed and i fill it myself so i know the format